# Elasticsearch query by max date

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have an index that is append only. Every change gets saved as a new document, together with a date property. In order to get the current active data I need to group all entities by their ID and get the one with the latest date. It should be possible to add a filter for that date. I have been playing around with aggregations but I got stuck with the scroll API.

Data example (note: id's are guids, dates are unix timestamps, using other values here to make it clearer)

```
   {"id": "<entityId_date>", "entityId", 1, "date": "2020-05-10", "value": { <JSON document> } }, 
   {"id": "<entityId_date>", "entityId", 1, "date": "2020-06-10", "value": { <JSON document> } }, 
   {"id": "<entityId_date>", "entityId", 2, "date": "2020-04-10", "value": { <JSON document> } }, 
   {"id": "<entityId_date>", "entityId", 2, "date": "2020-08-10", "value": { <JSON document> } },
   {"id": "<entityId_date>", "entityId", 3, "date": "2020-07-10", "value": { <JSON document> } }
```

Required results:

```
   {"id": "<entityId_date>", "entityId", 1, "date": "2020-06-10", "value": { <JSON document> } }, 
   {"id": "<entityId_date>", "entityId", 2, "date": "2020-08-10", "value": { <JSON document> } },
   {"id": "<entityId_date>", "entityId", 3, "date": "2020-07-10", "value": { <JSON document> } }
```

Tried the following query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "id_aggregate": {
      "terms": { 
          "field": "entityId"
       },
      "aggs": {
        "date_aggregate": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [{
                "date.ticks": {
                    "order": "desc"
                }
            }],
            "size": 1
          }
        }
     }
    }
  }
}
```

The result I get back is correct, but I only get the first X results back. I can set the size of the `id_aggregate`, but there could be thousands of documents.
With a normal search query, I'd be able to use the Scroll API, but this is not possible with aggregations.

I have looked into using partitions, but that doesn't help me either, because sometimes there will be very few documents and sometimes there will be loads. (This is kind of a base query, all other queries we execute will have additional filters specified).

How can I build a query that fetches documents by their max date and is scrollable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use composite aggs to paginate and keep the `top_hits` agg to retrieve only the most recent doc:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "comp_parent": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "by_id": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "entityId"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "size": 10,                          <-- bucket size
        "after": {
          "by_id": "<entityId_date>_xyz"     <-- pagination 'cursor'
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
              {
                "date.ticks": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was looking into that. Unfortunately, we're still stuck on ES 5.7, so composite aggs are not available to us :-(

Comment: Gotcha. Are you already hitting some query timeouts or other limits with your current set up?

Comment: We have about a million documents in there. We don't always need to query them all, but there are times where we need 100K documents. That's not ideal for scrolling

Comment: Also, in the case that we need to filter, ES seems to filter first, then aggregate. That could lead to incorrect results: if an older document was changed in such a way that it doesn't meet the filter, we want to omit it from the results, and not retrieve the older version

Comment: Not sure I understand -- the older versions would indeed be omitted if you apply a time filter. Or are you saying that you don't know what filter you'd want beforehand?

Comment: I mean, if I filter on another property. eg: 
Create document with name "test", then insert another document with the same id with name "other". When I query something like "name: test" and group by max(date), I would like to first filter it down to the latest documents, then filter for the name, which would result in no documents found. But ES will first filter for the name and then take the latest document,